# Calculate the angle in a eclipse to match a given point

Tags: geometry

I need to find the angle (A in the diagram) to match a given point in a ellipse (Px, Py) in the diagram. The ellipse is not centered at the 0, 0, but I have all the data.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $$\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-y_0)^2}{b^2}=1$$ which is the general equation of an ellipse centred at $(x_0,y_0)$, then  we have $$x-x_0=a\cos \theta,~~y-y_0=b\sin \theta$$ and so $\tan\theta=\frac{a(y-y_0)}{b(x-x_0)}$. I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks!!

Comment: I am glad I could help. :-)

Comment: Nice feedback! +1